# Drop down list depenedent on a seperate sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to make a Google Sheet for some purpose which shall have details of various movies. Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10-4BWaK-zmTxmqr2ov7AvjQW-wAFR8NKXkICuCK1dTY/edit?usp=sharing

Now I have different sheets for different years as visible in the sheet. Now in the column `Platform` I want to expand the drop down. Obviously it will be time consuming if I edit every sheet individually. I also have another sheet with name `Platforms` which lists all option required in drop down of all sheets. So I there anyway that the drop down list is dependent on the data in `sheet Platforms`.
google-apps-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to data -> data validation and choose the "list from range" option then select the range you want in the "platforms" sheet.

#### Reference:

- [Create an in-cell dropdown list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103)